# my h4n noise problem

Tags: zoom-h4n

Peace and mercy of Allah

My problem with my H4N is when i start recording,without any sound in the room , the sound pointer  become very noisy during recording, so the recorded sound becomes very bad,

sometimes noisy become in the left mic only :As in the picture

and sometimes it become in both mic:As in the picture

by using external mic, the problem is disappear, but i want the internal mic

i want you to determine the cause of the problem and solved
Please note that I use this device for recording lessons and lectures.
and it's very important to me

I expect from you distinctive and fast answer

Please accept my thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The internal mics are pretty noisy, but they shouldn't be that noisy that you can't use the sound recorded. Is there perhaps a ventilation system in the rooms? Also, what is your recording level? Perhaps you're recording too loud or maybe listening too loud. Was there an attached image? I didn't see any

Comment: 
Thank you for your interest, actually sometimes the device works without any problem, and Sometimes the recording indicator indicates a high degree.
Normal room ventilation system
Mic among recording level (100-89)
Even if it were reduced to 30 recording indicator remains high
I can not add a"illustration picture" because I am a new member.........Sorry for any Linguistic errors

Comment: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=1cfe7f972b&view=att&th=1359d91ecc30cdb1&attid=0.2&disp=emb&realattid=ii_1359d9141718b119&zw
     
  

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=1cfe7f972b&view=att&th=1359d91ecc30cdb1&attid=0.1&disp=emb&realattid=ii_1359d91c156ac623&zw

Comment: The links don't work (they probably point to your gmail account which we cannot access), but you can upload pictures to something like http://photobucket.com/ and post the link here. Or perhaps you could post a small excerpt of a recording on soundcloud.com or audioboo.fm.

Comment: my problem with the device !
with no sound in the room, it records like this:
 
http://www4.0zz0.com/2012/02/24/07/143149872.png
 
and sometimes by right mic only , like this :
 
http://www4.0zz0.com/2012/02/24/08/323461379.png